# How can I pass the totalPrice to taxSum.js?

Tags: reactjs

While I'm trying to learn React, I started working on this project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/k223ynpy3

I still don't know Redux and trying to finish the app by using only React.

My next move would be passing the **totalPrice** from **productDetails** to **taxSum** component to calculate the VAT.(I hope this is the right approach)

But I am stuck at this point and don't know how to pass the **totalPrice** to **taxSum** component. 
Any help please?

Comment: You cannot, you have to move the state up.

Comment: [here's how to do that](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Can you group productDetails and taxSum components?

Comment: Your current setup, doesn't have any parent-child relationship you can use context api or with your current setup you can do like this https://codesandbox.io/s/0o0r6x7j0n

Comment: Is this what you guys mean with lifting up the state?
https://codesandbox.io/s/pwrkr9zv9x